# SQL many to many select

Tags: sql, mysql, many-to-many

```
category_product
---------------
id_category
id_product

product
---------------
id_product
id_manufacturer

manufacturer
---------------
id_manufacturer
name
```

How would I create an SQL query so that it selects all the names from manufacturer when id_category is equal to something?

Comment: Similar question (with lots of ways to do this): [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a straightforward inner join of the tables:

```
SELECT m.name, cp.id_category
FROM manufacturer as m
INNER JOIN product as p
    ON m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer
INNER JOIN category_product as cp
    ON p.id_product = cp.id_product
WHERE cp.id_category = 'some value'
```

Answer (score 15):

Query without joins will look like following :

```
SELECT m.name 
FROM manufacturer as m, product as p, category_product as cp 
WHERE cp.id_category = <your value>
      AND cp.id_product = p.id_product 
      AND p.id_manufacturer = m.id_manufacturer
```

Comment: This is not without joins. The joins are just implicit.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select M.name
From   manufacturer M
Where  M.id_manufacturer in ( Select P.id_manufacturer
                              From   product P
                              Where  P.id_product in ( Select C.id_product
                                                       From   category_product C
                                                       Where  C.id_category = ?))
```

Comment: I know this seems like a different approach, but the performance on such a query, given large tables, will be *horrific*...

Comment: No, in 90% of cases subquery better than join

Comment: And you have proof (case studies, links) of this statement? X-)

Comment: actually both JOIN and IN approaches result in the same DB query plan - so performance-wise it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM      category_product cp INNER JOIN
           product p ON cp.id_product = p.id_product INNER JOIN
           manufacturer m ON p.id_manufacturer = m.id_manufacturer
WHERE      cp.id_category = <your_value>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT m.name, cp.id_category
FROM manufacturer AS M INNER JOIN product AS P
    ON M.id_manufacturer = M.id_manufacturer
 INNER JOIN category_product AS CP
    ON P.id_product = CP.id_product 
WHERE cp.id_category = 'add value'
```

Comment: Can you format your code in a code block (4 spaces to the left of each line of code) and add some explanation for the code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I do not think it is particularly useful to answer a 8-year old question which already has several very good answers (one of them even being accepted).

Comment: Especially when this is a copy of that selected answer.