# How to write a Sql query to finds all participating rows in another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, relational-division

There are 3 tables: events, eventClients and clients.

Write a query that finds events that all clients have access to?

Inner join doesn't guarantee that all rows in a table participate so this doesn't help:

```
select * from events e
inner join eventclients ec on e.id = ec.eventid
inner join clients c on etc.clientid = c.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested `NOT EXISTS` to check this:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM   events e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM  client c 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM eventclients ec 
        WHERE ec.eventid = e.id AND c.id= ec.clientid 
    )
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/847d9/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: @TheLight: It returns all events where all available clients are in eventclients with the given  `eventid`. It's a little bit confusing because of the double negation. Side-note: `NOT EXISTS` is efficient and has no pitfalls(nullable columns) like other approaches. Have a look: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
  FROM events e LEFT JOIN eventclients ec
    ON e.id = ec.eventid LEFT JOIN clients c
    ON ec.clientid = c.id
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name
HAVING COUNT(ec.clientid) = 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95004/4)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean *event* has a many-to-many relationship with *client* and *event_client* is the bridge table between them, then you should any of the many other questions asking about a SQL join across a many-to-many relationship.

[SQL many to many select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486644/sql-many-to-many-select)

[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)